# What is a "demi" (in a university setting)

Tags: slang, abbreviations, colloquialisms

My university computer science department recently sent out a letter asking for "students to *demi* for our first-year modules". The letter makes mention of it several times, such as "*demis* must have passed X course" and "preference will be given to those *demis* also available for X" (emphasis mine).

What is a "demi"? It is an abbreviation for some other word, or just some colloquialism?

I can infer from the context that it's some kind of tutor, but I'm curious where this word comes from.

Comment: Whoever wrote that is not big on communication. :-/ I did find one reference on LinkedIn saying "I have been employed by the University of Stellenbosch as a demi/tutor", but jeesh, "demi" doesn't appear in any dictionary I can find, so it's pretty silly to use the word without clarification.

Comment: "Demi" (also, "semi") is of Greek origin and may mean "half". So perhaps "demi" is a person with a "half" working contract (as tutor etc.)?

Comment: It could possibly be short for 'demonstrator'. When I was briefly a science undergraduate many years ago, demonstrators were postgraduate students employed to help us with practical sessions in the lab.

Comment: @KateBunting That sounds quite plausible, considering if demonstrator were shortened to "demo" it would change the sound of the word, so "demi" makes more sense.

Comment: I wonder if it has any relation to the Oxford term "demy"